# How to use AutoMapper to map info from an object within an object to another object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

Suppose I have 3 object classes in my ASP.Net core 5 project. I am using the package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection. The classes are:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public double OrderPrice{ get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer 
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
}

public class OrderODTO 
{
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public double OrderPrice{ get; set; }
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I use Automapper between Order and OrderODTO, the OrderId and OrderPrice values will be mapped, however the CustomerName is always null even though the object customer is included in the order object. For example

```
order 
{
    orderId: 1,
    orderPrice: 3.99,
    customerId: 2,
    customer {
        customerId: 2,
        customerName: "Jack"
   }
}
```

so how to use Automapper to map from both order and customer objects into 1 object orderODTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a mapping between Order and OrderODTO:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderODTO>()
            .ForMember("CustomerName", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.CustomerName)));
```

Using a mapper based on this config you will get the desired result

```
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        Order order = new Order()
        {
            OrderId = 1,
            OrderPrice = 3.99,
            CustomerId = 2,
            Customer = new Customer() {
                CustomerId = 2,
                CustomerName = "Jack"
            }
        };
OrderODTO orderOdto = mapper.Map<Order, OrderODTO>(order);
```

As a result:

```
orderOdto 
{
    OrderId: 1,
    OrderPrice: 3.99,
    CustomerName: "Jack"
}
```